# "Parsing error: Unexpected token" on node shebang line

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I am writing a shell script using node but when try to lint the code using eslint I get the following error:

Parsing error: Unexpected token function
and it points to the very first line which is: `#!/usr/bin/env node`

I am not sure if I am missing something or if I should just disable the error in eslint.

This is my eslintrc file I hope it helps. I am suspicious about parserOptions

```js
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es6": true
    },
"parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module"
},
    "rules": {
        "comma-dangle": 0,
        "no-cond-assign": 2,
        "no-console": 0,
        "no-constant-condition": 1,
        "no-control-regex": 2,
        "no-debugger": 2,
        "no-dupe-args": 2,
        "no-dupe-keys": 2,
        "no-duplicate-case": 0,
        "no-empty-character-class": 2,
        "no-empty": 2,
        "no-ex-assign": 2,
        "no-extra-boolean-cast": 2,
        "no-extra-parens": 1,
        "no-extra-semi": 2,
        "no-func-assign": 2,
        "no-inner-declarations": 1,
        "no-invalid-regexp": 2,
        "no-irregular-whitespace": 2,
        "no-negated-in-lhs": 2,
        "no-obj-calls": 2,
        "no-prototype-builtins": 0,
        "no-regex-spaces": 2,
        "no-sparse-arrays": 1,
        "no-unexpected-multiline": 2,
        "no-unreachable": 2,
        "no-unsafe-finally": 2,
        "use-isnan": 2,
        "valid-jsdoc": 0,
        "valid-typeof": 2,


        "accessor-pairs": 0,
        "array-callback-return": 2,
        "block-scoped-var": 0,
        "complexity": 0,
        "consistent-return": 0,
        "curly": [2, "multi-line"],
        "default-case": 0,
        "dot-location": [2, "property"],
        "dot-notation": 2,
        "eqeqeq": 0,
        "guard-for-in": 0,
        "no-alert": 2,
        "no-caller": 0,
        "no-case-declarations": 0,
        "no-div-regex": 2,
        "no-else-return": 0,
        "no-empty-function": 0,
        "no-empty-pattern": 2,
        "no-eq-null": 2,
        "no-eval": 2,
        "no-extend-native": 0,
        "no-extra-bind": 1,
        "no-extra-label": 2,
        "no-fallthrough": 0,
        "no-floating-decimal": 0,
        "no-implicit-coercion": 0,
        "no-implicit-globals": 0,
        "no-implied-eval": 2,
        "no-invalid-this": 1,
        "no-iterator": 2,
        "no-labels": 2,
        "no-lone-blocks": 2,
        "no-loop-func": 2,
        "no-magic-numbers": 0,
        "no-multi-spaces": 2,
        "no-multi-str": 0,
        "no-native-reassign": 2,
        "no-new-func": 1,
        "no-new-wrappers": 0,
        "no-new": 2,
        "no-octal-escape": 0,
        "no-octal": 0,
        "no-param-reassign": 0,
        "no-process-env": 0,
        "no-proto": 2,
        "no-redeclare": 2,
        "no-return-assign": 2,
        "no-script-url": 2,
        "no-self-assign": 2,
        "no-self-compare": 2,
        "no-sequences": 2,
        "no-throw-literal": 2,
        "no-unmodified-loop-condition": 0,
        "no-unused-expressions": 0,
        "no-unused-labels": 2,
        "no-useless-call": 2,
        "no-useless-concat": 2,
        "no-useless-escape": 2,
        "no-void": 0,
        "no-warning-comments": 1,
        "no-with": 2,
        "radix": 2,
        "vars-on-top": 0,
        "wrap-iife": 0,
        "yoda": 2,


        "strict": 0,


        "init-declarations": 0,
        "no-catch-shadow": 2,
        "no-delete-var": 2,
        "no-label-var": 2,
        "no-restricted-globals": 0,
        "no-shadow-restricted-names": 2,
        "no-shadow": [2, {"allow": ["err"]}],
        "no-undef-init": 2,
        "no-undef": 2,
        "no-undefined": 0,
        "no-unused-vars": 2,
        "no-use-before-define": 0,

        "callback-return": 2,
        "global-require": 0,
        "handle-callback-err": 2,
        "no-mixed-requires": 2,
        "no-new-require": 2,
        "no-path-concat": 2,
        "no-process-exit": 2,
        "no-restricted-imports": 0,
        "no-restricted-modules": 0,
        "no-sync": 1,


        "array-bracket-spacing": [2, "never"],
        "block-spacing": 0,
        "brace-style": 2,
        "camelcase": 1,
        "comma-spacing": [2, {"before": false, "after": true}],
        "comma-style": 2,
        "computed-property-spacing": 2,
        "consistent-this": 2,
        "eol-last": 2,
        "func-names": 0,
        "func-style": 0,
        "id-blacklist": 0,
        "id-length": 0,
        "id-match": 0,
        "indent": ["error", 4],
        "jsx-quotes": 0,
        "key-spacing": 2,
        "keyword-spacing": [2, {
            "before": true,
            "after": true,
            "overrides": {
                "if": {"after": false},
                "for": {"after": false},
                "while": {"after": false},
                "catch": {"after": false}
            }
        }],
        "linebreak-style": 2,
        "lines-around-comment": 0,
        "max-depth": 1,
        "max-len": [1, 200],
        "max-lines": 0,
        "max-nested-callbacks": 2,
        "max-params": 0,
        "max-statements": 0,
        "max-statements-per-line": 0,
        "new-cap": 0,
        "new-parens": 2,
        "newline-after-var": 0,
        "newline-before-return": 0,
        "newline-per-chained-call": [
            "error",
            {"ignoreChainWithDepth": 2}
        ],
        "no-array-constructor": 2,
        "no-bitwise": 0,
        "no-continue": 0,
        "no-inline-comments": 0,
        "no-lonely-if": 2,
        "no-mixed-operators": 0,
        "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 2,
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": 2,
        "no-negated-condition": 0,
        "no-nested-ternary": 0,
        "no-new-object": 2,
        "no-plusplus": 0,
        "no-restricted-syntax": 0,
        "no-spaced-func": 2,
        "no-ternary": 0,

        "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
        "no-unneeded-ternary": 2,
        "no-whitespace-before-property": 2,
        "object-curly-newline": 0,
        "object-curly-spacing": 0,
        "object-property-newline": 0,
        "one-var": [2, "never"],
        "one-var-declaration-per-line": 2,
        "operator-assignment": 0,
        "operator-linebreak": [1, "before"],
        "padded-blocks": [2, "never"],
        "quote-props": [2, "as-needed"],
        "quotes": [2, "single", { "avoidEscape": true }],
        "require-jsdoc": 0,
        "semi-spacing": 2,
        "sort-imports": 0,
        "semi": 2,
        "sort-vars": 0,
        "space-before-blocks": 2,
        "space-before-function-paren": [2, "never"],
        "space-in-parens": 2,
        "space-infix-ops": 2,
        "space-unary-ops": 2,
        "spaced-comment": 0,
        "unicode-bom": 0,
        "wrap-regex": 0,

        "arrow-body-style": [2, "as-needed"],
        "arrow-parens": [2, "as-needed"],
        "arrow-spacing": 2,
        "constructor-super": 2,
        "generator-star-spacing": 0,
        "no-class-assign": 2,
        "no-confusing-arrow": 2,
        "no-const-assign": 2,
        "no-dupe-class-members": 2,
        "no-duplicate-imports": 2,
        "no-new-symbol": 2,
        "no-this-before-super": 2,
        "no-useless-computed-key": 2,
        "no-useless-constructor": 2,
        "no-useless-rename": 2,
        "no-var": 0,
        "object-shorthand": 1,
        "prefer-arrow-callback": 0,
        "prefer-const": 0,
        "prefer-reflect": 1,
        "prefer-rest-params": 1,
        "prefer-spread": 1,
        "prefer-template": 1,
        "require-yield": 2,
        "rest-spread-spacing": ["error", "never"],
        "template-curly-spacing": 2,
        "yield-star-spacing": [2, "after"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first line is not JavaScript. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please post your eslint config file.

Comment: Yeah, the first line is not js, but it is a valid comment which it should allow my js to be an executable shell program.

Comment: JavaScript uses `//` for comments, not `#`.

Comment: If you're writing in JS, you don't have a shell script, you have a JS script.

Comment: @melpomene You *can* write a shebang line in a node/JS script and that works. Only eslint isn't happy with it.

Comment: you are right @melpomene but with nodejs the rules are a bit different. Yeah, the first line is a shebang that allows shell scripts to be written with js. I have changed  the sourcetype to script but still, eslint still complains

Comment: After awhile I finally realized, I did not give much context to my question. I had this piece of code `async function foo() {}`, and es-lint would complain about unrecognized token 'function'. And that is because, JS only has support for async functions out of the box by ES2017, so I just had to update my eslint configurations to parse ES2017 instead of ES2015. Honestly, at that time I posted this question, this was a foreign concept for me, I just expected things to work, now I am more aware of what code I am writing, and how the tooling is parsing it.

Comment: The problem was that I did not have the correct ESnext version in order to properly parse 'async function foo()'. I simply upgraded to ES11